# Flex focusOut event on TextInput and pop-up does not remove focus?

Tags: apache-flex, events, focus, flash-builder

I have a flex app with several fields and one text field with a focusOut event:

```
<mx:FormItem label="Last" x="226" y="1">
    <s:TextInput id="lastNameClientTextInput" text="@{_currentEditClient.lastName}" change="textFieldChangeCapitalize(event)" focusOut="lastNameClientTextInput_focusOutHandler(event)"/>
</mx:FormItem>
```

As expected, when I tab or click out of the field after typing a value it executes my "lastNameClientTextInput_focusOutHandler" method which simply pops-up a new window:

```
protected function lastNameClientTextInput_focusOutHandler(event:FocusEvent):void
        {

                clientSearchPopUp = new ClientListWindow();
                PopUpManager.addPopUp(clientSearchPopUp, this, true);
                PopUpManager.centerPopUp(clientSearchPopUp);                    

        }
```

That window will do a  "PopUpManager.removePopUp(this);" when the user clicks the close button.

However, the problem is when the window closes, the focus is back on the lastNameClientTextInput!  I am unable to click or tab out of the field!

When I tab out I do initially see the ibeam cursor move from the last name field to the next field in tab order (address) and then my window pops-up.  When I close the window it moves BACK to the last name field and highlights the value.

It is as if I need to do something to validate the focusOut event?

Comment: I'm curious, why would you ever have a popup *after* a focus out on a textinput?  It's a very weird, non-standard UX behavior.

Comment: Person types a first and last name, adding a new client, presses tab (or clicks out), the app is doing a duplicate check and popping up a list of possible duplicates.   Call it weird, but that's just how I have always seen it done in most business applications that have a customer/client duplicate name check feature.  Instead of making the user manually search first, it potentially can save some clicks/steps, especially if it's an uncommon last name.

Comment: Instead of a popup, wouldn't you rather has a dropdownlist instead? Like a search completion box? (think google, but instead gives you possible names). If that's the case, you don't need a popup and don't need to check 'onFocusOut'.  You should do it on 'change'.

Comment: I went with the drop-down list concept,  it worked well.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try using valueCommit rather than focusOut.  You could also listen for the popup being removed and set focus manually.

HTH;

Amy

Comment: Tried it, but it works the same as the change event, meaning every character I type it throws a valueCommit event.   Even so, it seems to be doing the same thing - the pop-up comes up, when the pop-up closes the focus goes back to the last name field with the value highlighted.   I guess for now I can manually set focus to the next field down (address), but seems like a hack.

Answer (score 0):

Late I know, but Flex may be referring to the FocusManager.lastFocus property to resume focus from the last time the component was active. When triggering the pop up, try calling:

```
(focusManager as FocusManager).mx_internal::lastFocus = null;
```